# Add error message to CustomValidator

Tags: asp.net

I'm tring to add an error message to a CustomValidator by catching a potentail script attack implementing IHttpHandler im using the below method, but it just seems to kill the page as the page ends up blank, any ideas?

```
public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            base.ProcessRequest(context);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestValidationException ex)
        {
           DisplayCustomMessageInValidationSummary("< or > characters are not allowed");    
        }
    }

private void DisplayCustomMessageInValidationSummary(string message)
{

    CustomValidator CustomValidatorCtrl = new CustomValidator();
    CustomValidatorCtrl.IsValid = false;
    CustomValidatorCtrl.ErrorMessage = message;
    this.Page.Controls.Add(CustomValidatorCtrl);

}
```

Thanks
Darren